# I keep getting dependency and "lsb not configured" errors when I try to install any software with apt-get install

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, printing

Okay, so my ultimate goal is to install my Epson WF-2630 AIO printer.  Upon trying to do this, I found that trying to install any package w/apt causes the same dependency error:

```
jen@DotySupreme:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 223896 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking epson-inkjet-printer-escpr (1.4.1-1lsb3.2) over (1.4.1-1lsb3.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr depends on lsb (>= 3.2); however:
  Package lsb is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package epson-inkjet-printer-escpr (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr
```

So I tried following instructions from several posts:

1. [apt-get install can't install any software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892248/apt-get-install-cant-install-any-software)

   - After reading this one, I think my error might be because I once ran autoremove, but I don't know how to shut it off.
2. [Apt-get fails to install any software since latest update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585688/apt-get-fails-to-install-any-software-since-latest-update)

   - I don't think this one will help, because I don't have a process to kill.
3. [Errors when trying to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810261/errors-when-trying-to-install)

   - The comment "@tlo I fixed it myself somr kind og command that's turns the terminal purpel and it say yes or no I choose yes and boom it fixed everything sudo dpkg -configue -a then sudo apt-get update" says that he answered his own question, but doesn't give me enough information to know what he did.
4. [How to install Epson printer drivers on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771427/how-to-install-epson-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1)

   - I added the trusty sources, but it doesn't add the printer, and when I manually select either the .rpm or .deb, I get a list of dot matrix printers to choose from.

When I try to use the gui to install the printer, and tell it to download the drivers itself, it just sits there frozen.

---

I've run several commands:

```
jen@DotySupreme:~$ sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 lsb-core : Depends: libc6:i386 or
                     libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

jen@DotySupreme:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,275 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,811 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 223896 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.23-0ubuntu7_i386.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu7_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu7_i386.deb
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

jen@DotySupreme:~$ sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

jen@DotySupreme:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zlib1g:i386:
 zlib1g:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package zlib1g:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-core:
 lsb-core depends on libc6:i386 | libc6-i386; however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not installed.
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 lsb-core depends on zlib1g:i386 | lib32z1; however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.
  Package lib32z1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cups (2.1.3-4) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb:
 lsb depends on lsb-core (>= 9.20160110ubuntu0.2); however:
  Package lsb-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcc1:i386:
 libgcc1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgcc1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr depends on lsb (>= 3.2); however:
  Package lsb is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package epson-inkjet-printer-escpr (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-printing:
 lsb-printing depends on lsb-core (>= 9.20160110ubuntu0.2); however:
  Package lsb-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-printing (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zlib1g:i386
 lsb-core
 cups
 lsb
 libgcc1:i386
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr
 lsb-printing

jen@DotySupreme:~$ sudo apt-get clean
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

---

UPDATE, tried to install synaptic:

```
jen@DotySupreme:~$ sudo apt install synaptic
[sudo] password for jen: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
synaptic is already the newest version (0.83).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 lsb-core : Depends: libc6:i386 or
                     libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb and the Epson website lists the epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.13-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb as the version they recommend http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=55539&DSCCHK=5ef6ec128765534a989152269045f12fc58077f2 .so if you download and save that   .for a new search,I start here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX and enter the printer number.

I see various error messages "ibc6:i386 is not installed"; and "Package lsb-core is not configured yet" please check lsb installed; ideally using synaptic which one can install with `sudo apt install synaptic`and if lsb is installed I would try again in a terminal with `sudo apt install epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.13-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`

new terminology I understand is to just use apt install

Comment: Thank you for the correct file, I didn't notice the discrepancy.  However, I still get dependency problems when using apt.  I updated my question to include the results of trying to install synaptic.

Comment: the apt script says "E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages"so do try that; "sudo apt-get -f install"here is a link to a thread and read post #7 as the original poster sorted his issues in that https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=242497